# Bugzilla 4.2 to 5.0.4 'Can't locate parent.pm in @INC'

Tags: sysadmin

I've just updated Bugzilla from 4.2 to 5.0 on our Centos 6 vps, using the tarball method:

```
bash$ cd /var/www/html
bash$ wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/webtools/bugzilla-5.0.4.tar.gz
bash$ tar xzvf bugzilla-5.0.4.tar.gz
bash$ cd bugzilla-5.0.4
bash$ cp ../bugzilla/localconfig* .
bash$ cp -r ../bugzilla/data .
bash$ cd ..
bash$ mv bugzilla bugzilla.old
bash$ mv bugzilla-5.0.4 bugzilla
```

I'm getting the following error from `./checksetup.pl`:

> Can't locate parent.pm in @INC (@INC contains: . lib /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at Bugzilla/Constants.pm line 14.
>
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Constants.pm line 14.
>
> Compilation failed in require at ./checksetup.pl line 27.
>
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./checksetup.pl line 27.

What did I do wrong and/or how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to install a new perl module

```
yum install perl-parent
```

then I had to install `make` to install other dependencies:

```
cpan
o conf make '/usr/bin/make' #or path to your make
o conf commit
```